# VBA pivot table sum/count button

Tags: vba, excel

as stated in the title i'm trying to make a button  that swaps betweend the count and the sum in a particular pivot table field i could make it in two but i've troubles with the IF statement this is what i came up with :

```
Sub Count()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Sum of SP/UOM")
        .Caption = "Count of SP/UOM"
        .Function = xlCount
    End With

End Sub

Sub Sum()
'
' Sum Macro
'

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Count of SP/UOM")
        .Caption = "Sum of SP/UOM"
        .Function = xlSum
    End With

End Sub
```

If someone has an idea on how to make it I would be thankful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a loop like this:

```
Dim pf As PivotField
For Each pf In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").DataFields
    If pf.SourceName = "SP/UOM" Then
        If pf.Function = xlSum Then
            pf.Caption = "Count of SP/UOM"
            pf.Function = xlCount
        Else
            pf.Caption = "Sum of SP/UOM"
            pf.Function = xlSum
        End If
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , sadly it gives me a syntax error for the "For each pf..." line

Comment: @Basho - check again, there was a typo.